# Using Excel Vlookup to match cells in another sheet with special characters

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I found that I could match cells from another sheet but the cells with additional special characters does not work as expected.

My formula in C2 = IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:M,3,false),"No Match")
It works properly until I hit cells with special characters.

Example:
In Sheet 1

```
A     B    C
ABC  XXX   0
ABC@ XXX   **No Match**
```

In Sheet 2

```
M
ABC
ABC@
```

The formula will need to change for it to match cells in Sheet 2.

I need the results to reflect correctly in Sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

The formula should work just fine. Maybe there's an additional space on either the lookup value or on the lookup range.

`"ABC@"` is not equal to `"ABC@ "` (notice the space on the second value). Other variations of such exist.

You can test out the formula by copying the `"ABC@"` from `sheet1` to the `"ABC@"` of `sheet2`, and the formula should correctly return your data.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I suspect the problem lies in col_index_num which is 3 and I have no values at all in column 3 as I am just searching through sheet 2 to match text.

Comment: If the col_index_num of 3 is working with `ABC` then it should as well work with `ABC@`. I just tried your example and it works fine.

Comment: ya I tried it works if my sheet2 cells are in column A. the issue now is my working file sheet2, the target cells are somewhere in column B30 to column M100 and it sort of messed up the formula.